# Lisp function returns NIL when used in a menu function but otherwise works

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp, slime, abcl

I wrote a function to query a small database program I'm writing for school. This function searches by name. When I run the function by itself it works. When I run it within the menu it does not work (it returns NIL). 
Here is everything relevant:

```
(defun prompt-read (prompt)                                                    
  (format *query-io* "~a: " prompt)                                            
  (force-output *query-io*)                                                    
  (read-line *query-io*)) 

(defun search-name (name)                                                      
  (remove-if-not                                                               
   #'(lambda (cat) (equal (getf cat :name) name)) *db*))                       

(defun input-name ()                                                           
  (search-name                                                                 
   (prompt-read "Name")))

(defun search-menu ()                                                          
  (print "1) Search Name")                                                     
  (print "2) Search Color")                                                    
  (print "3) Search Min. Weight")                                              
  (print "4) Search Min. Experience")                                          
  (print "5) Search Min. Length")                                              
  (setf choose (read))                                                         
  (cond ((= choose 1)(input-name))                                             
        ((= choose 2)(print "Color"))                                          
        ((= choose 3)(print "Weight"))                                         
        ((= choose 4)(print "XP"))                                             
        ((= choose 5)(print "Color"))                                          
  )                                                                            
  NIL                                                                          
)
```

Right now I am only working on getting the name search working, the rest of the menu is just placeholders. When I run "input-name" (which uses search-name) by itself it returns the correct result. When I try the first option from the search-menu (which also runs "input-name") it returns NIL. I am wondering why when I run it by itself works but not when used with that menu. If anybody needs any other information feel free to ask. I will try my best to provide it. Also, I am a beginner so please forgive me.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You might need to show us an interaction. As the function `search-menu` currently is, it always returns `NIL`, since that is the last value explicitly in your code - see the second last line of `search-menu`. How can it return anything other than `NIL`?

Comment: Additionally: the variable `choose` is undefined in your code. `setf` does not define variables - it only sets them.

Comment: Hint: try to understand the difference between *printing something in a function*, *returning a value from a function* and *printing the evaluation result in a READ-EVEL-PRINT-LOOP*.

Answer (score 2):

If you want output in a program, then you need to print something.

```
(defun example ()
  1000)
```

The above function prints nothing. It just returns a number.

If we call it in the read-eval-print-loop:

```
CL-USER 134 > (defun example ()
                1000)
EXAMPLE

CL-USER 135 > (example)
1000
```

You see that 1000 gets printed. But why?

We run it in the READ-EVAL-**PRINT**-LOOP. The read, eval, **PRINT**, loop.

Means: the Lisp system is printing the returned value of the evaluation, but not your code.

Now we add a **print** call:

```
CL-USER 136 > (defun example ()
                (print 1000))
EXAMPLE

CL-USER 137 > (example)

1000 
1000
```

It's printed twice!

```
CL-USER 137 > (example)

1000     ; <- the function example prints 
1000     ; <- the read-eval-print-loop prints the result
```

So our function now prints something itself, since it calls `PRINT`.

Now this works:

```
CL-USER 138 > (defun call-the-example ()
                (example)
                (values))
CALL-THE-EXAMPLE

CL-USER 139 > (call-the-example)

1000
```

We can call the `example` function, the function prints something, and the REPL prints nothing.

The REPL prints nothing, since `call-the-example` returns nothing. It returns no value.

**Thus you need to add a PRINT call**

You are right to add a print call, but the reason is simply that before you did not print and the call to `(input-name)` did not print. You were calling `(input-name)` in the READ-EVAL-PRINT-LOOP, which then prints the result. Not your code, but the REPL did output.

**Style: undefined variable**

```
(defun foo ()
  (setf bar 10)  ; <- BAR is undefined
  (print bar)    ; <- BAR is undefined
  (setf bar 20)  ; <- BAR is undefined
  (print bar))   ; <- BAR is undefined
```

Write this instead - using `LET` to define a local variable:

```
(defun foo ()
  (let ((bar 10))    ; define BAR
    (print bar)      ; BAR is defined
    (setf bar 20)    ; BAR is defined
    (print bar)))    ; BAR is defined
```

Answer (score 0):

`search-menu` doesn't do anything with the return value from `input-name`. A function returns the value of the last expression that it executes, and the last expression in `search-menu` is `NIL`, so that's what it returns.

If you want it to return the value of the `cond` expression, remove `NIL` from the end.

You should also use `let` to declare a local variable, rather than assigning the undefined variable `choose`.

```
(defun search-menu ()
  (print "1) Search Name")
  (print "2) Search Color")
  (print "3) Search Min. Weight")
  (print "4) Search Min. Experience")
  (print "5) Search Min. Length")
  (let ((choose (read)))
    (cond ((= choose 1) (input-name))
          ((= choose 2) (print "Color"))
          ((= choose 3) (print "Weight"))
          ((= choose 4) (print "XP"))
          ((= choose 5) (print "Color")))))
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up finding a solution that works by simply using print in the input-name function. This function only has to show results so this works just fine.

```
(defun input-name ()                                                           
  (print                                                                       
  (search-name                                                                 
   (prompt-read "Name"))))
```

Same function as before but with an added print. Now it also works in the menu.

Comment: But now when you run the function by itself, the result is printed twice. Do you understand why?

Comment: @RainerJoswig yeah that’s fine though. This is just a beginner project and all I have to do is show the correct results on screen.

Comment: The question was: do you understand why it's printed twice?

Comment: And I said “yeah”.